# JAVAFX tablecolumn

Tags: javafx

I am trying to get my javafx(using scene builder) to read in a list of employee id and name. Most of it works, but I want the names that have been added to the list to show when I click the show button. Also, I created a tableview in scene builder and I want that window to pop up when the "show" button is clicked. Is the only way to do this with a obeservablelist? How can accomplish this. My code so far is below. I didn't attach the employee class or the primary fxml file, but i Can if it helps.

```
enter
package queue5230;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class FXMLDocumentController {

    Queue<Employee> empQu = new LinkedList<>();

    String name;
    String startTime;
    String endTime;
    int id;

    @FXML
    private TextField employeeId;

    @FXML
    private TextField employeeName;

    @FXML
    private Button insertButton;

    @FXML 
    private Button removeButton;

    @FXML 
    private Button showButton;

    @FXML 
    private TableView<Employee> showTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> idField;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Employee, String> nameField;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleTextInsert(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        if(insertButton == event.getSource())
        {
         //get values entered   
         id = Integer.parseInt(employeeId.getText());
         name = employeeName.getText();

         //get time entered
         Date d = new Date();

         //get the date format
         startTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(d);

         //Create employee object
         Employee emp = new Employee(id, name, startTime);

         //ad object to queue
         empQu.add(emp);

        }else if(removeButton == event.getSource()){

            Employee empr = empQu.remove();

            Date end = new Date();

            endTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(end);

            String elapse = getElapsedTime(empr.getTime(), endTime);

        }else if(showButton == event.getSource()){


            Stage stage;
            Parent root;
            String str = "ID  NAME  TIME START\n\n";

            Iterator<Employee> it = empQu.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){

                //str += it.next() + "\n";

            }


            stage = new Stage();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Show.fxml"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.showAndWait();


        }


    }

    public String getElapsedTime(String starting, String ending)
    {
        String startToken[] = starting.split(":");
        String endToken[] = ending.split(":");

        int hours = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(startToken[0])-Integer.parseInt(endToken[0]));
        int minutes = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(startToken[1])-Integer.parseInt(endToken[1]));
        int seconds = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(startToken[2])-Integer.parseInt(endToken[2]));

        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }


    public void initialize() {



    }    

}
```

code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="queue5230.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="31.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="540.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="showTable" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="401.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="idField" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameField" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code. You have two FXML files, is that right? Which controller are you showing, the one for the main file or the one for the one you load with the "Show" button?

Comment: Yes, I have two FXML files and both FXML files use the same controller. The FXML file I posted is the one that will pop up once the show button on the primary FXML is clicked.

Comment: Don't use the same class for both controllers - it gets really confusing as you won't be able to keep track of which instance has which fields initialized. Use a different controller class for each FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

fine in this page https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm, there are example of how to show a object in the TableView, but you can define in the fxml:

```xml
<TableColumn fx:id="nameField" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" >
     <cellValueFactory>
         <javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory property="the field name"/> 
     </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

your fxml  code, it will look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="queue5230.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="31.0" layoutY="22.0" prefHeight="361.0" prefWidth="540.0">
         <children>
            <TableView fx:id="showTable" layoutX="101.0" layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="340.0" prefWidth="401.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="idField" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" >
                      <cellValueFactory>
                        <javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory property="id"/> 
                      </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameField" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" >
                    <cellValueFactory>
                       <javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory property="name"/> 
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
              </columns>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```